# NFS mount points are going off/NFS compound failed for server mashost

Tags: solaris, nfs, heap-dump

We have an application in solaris during specific test case we will generate heap dump which will be written in to the server at specific path during this case we are getting following error in trace file 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Dumping heap to /ossrc/upgrade/JREheapdumps/java_pid16092.hprof ...
Dump file is incomplete: I/O error

and in /var/adm/messages we could see 
Oct 28 13:00:10 ossuas2 nfs: [ID 733954 kern.info] NOTICE: [NFS4][Server: mashost][Mntpt: /ossrc/upgrade]NFS server mashost not
responding; still trying
Oct 28 13:02:53 ossuas2 nfs: [ID 733954 kern.info] NOTICE: [NFS4][Server: mashost][Mntpt: /usr/local]NFS server mashost not
responding; still trying
Oct 28 13:04:53 ossuas2 nfs: [ID 733954 kern.info] NOTICE: [NFS4][Server: mashost][Mntpt: /etc/opt/ericsson]NFS server mashost not
responding; still trying

Can anyone please help here why we are getting this problem and can any tell us can an application cause this impact on mashost ..????

Answer (score 0):

First things first, check out the NFS service w/ **svcbundle** and **svcs** -- when it crashes, run:

```
# svcs -x nfs/client
```

on the client, and

```
# svcs -x nfs/server
```

on the server. I would expect one or both to be in a "maintenance" state. (You may see it fails to start properly at all). If it is in a maintenance mode, you should see a row marked "Reason:" that says why.

You might see "offline" -- in that case, **startd** will attempt to reboot the service multiple times and, if it fails after five attempts or hangs indefinitely, places it into "maintenance" state and stops restarting.

Check the logs in

```
/var/svc/log/<service-name FMRI>.log
```

There will be one on your client machine under "network-nfs-client:default" (probably, may have a name other than 'default' if it's been changed manually), and one on the server under "network-nfs-server:default"

See what you can glean from those.

---

**svcbundle** is all the time taking snapshots as backups of services, so you can try reverting to one of those.

```
#  svcs -s nfs/server:default
svc:/network/nfs/server:default>  listsnap
svc:/network/nfs/server:default>  revert start [name_of_snapshot]
svc:/network/nfs/server:default>  quit

#  svcadm refresh nfs/server:default
#  svcadm restart nfs/server:default
```

Make sure to include the ":default" tag, or if you saw a different tag from "svcs nfs/server" include it, that name defines an *instance* of the service, every running service is an instance.

If the process is failing to boot, you might have to look at the XML manifest under /lib/svc/manifest/network/nfs/ -- inside, you'll see dependencies (and services dependent on this one), then "exec_method"s, which define how the service starts, stops and restarts.

Instead of snapshots, you can can also restore it to default: use **svccfg -s <*FMRI*> delete** to clear it, then **svcadm refresh <*FMRI*>** and **svcadm enable <*FMRI*>**.

---

If the service is in *maintenance* state, once you've isolated and fixed the problem, you can manually clear that state by running **svcadm clear <*FMRI*>**.